# How is adding a 3x3 transformation to an inertia tensor and adding the transpose of that 3x3 transformation matrix not cancelling each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, tensors

We know $T^{-1}=T^{T}$ when the transformation matrix is orthogonal.

We know when using inetia tensor in 3d the global inertia for a given as

$I=R\cdot I^{'}\cdot R^T$

where $I'$ is the local inertia. So my question is why does these two transformations not cancel out. Essentially you a certain transformation to get some rotation, then multiply 3x3 tensor and then we go back start the transformation of the start. Nothing happened.

I see it as $1/2\cdot I \cdot 2$ Why write 2 and half when they cancel eachother out. This ordeal is confusing to me. I have added a picture of the whole "proof" but I hope my message got through.

[image: Taken from: http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/moi/triten.html]

Comment: Have you tried doing some concrete calculation? Just pick some arbitrary matrices and _see_ that it doesn't always cancel.

Comment: But why? Intuitively it does not make sense.

Comment: Does it make intuitive sense to you that matrices commute? Because to me, it doesn't (and also, they generally don't commute). And as a corollary, it makes intuitive sense to me that you _can't_ in general write $TIT^{-1} = ITT^{-1}$.

Comment: My problem is not commuting. My intuition tells me that $TIT^{−1}=I$ since they both get cancelled in my head. As you say they don't always cancel each other but when do they?

Comment: They cancel when $I$ and $T$ commute, so that you can write $TIT^{-1} = ITT^{-1} = I$.

Comment: Thanks now I got.